How do I randomly label vertex?
I want to find the harmonic labeling for the Hanoi H_3 graph. I coded it using Python with the following code:
How do I randomly label vertices with numbers from 0 to 38?
import networkx as nx

H3 = nx.Graph()
H3.add_edges_from([(1 ,2), (2 ,3), (3 ,1), (2 ,4), (4 ,5), (5 ,6), (6 ,4),
               (6 ,8), (3 ,7), (7 ,8), (8 ,9), (9 ,7), (5 ,10), (10 ,11),
               (11 ,12), (12 ,10), (11 ,13), (13 ,14), (14 ,15), (15 ,13), (15 ,17),
               (12 ,16), (16 ,17), (17 ,18), (18 ,16), (18, 23), (9 ,19), (19 ,20),
               (20 ,21), (21 ,19), (20 ,22), (22 ,23), (23 ,24), (24 ,22), (24 ,26),
               (21 ,25), (25 ,26), (26 ,27), (27 ,25)])

# Assign initial labels to the nodes
node_labels = {node: i for i, node in enumerate(H3.nodes, start=1)}
nx.set_node_attributes(H3, node_labels, 'label')

# Calculate harmonious labels for the edges
edge_labels = {(u, v): (node_labels[u] + node_labels[v]) % (H3.number_of_edges()) for u, v in H3.edges}
nx.set_edge_attributes(H3, edge_labels, 'label')

I used that code, but the vertex labels don't start at 0 and are labelled in order.

What about randomly sampling the nodes to give them a new label?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from random import sample

H3 = nx.Graph()
H3.add_edges_from([(1 ,2), (2 ,3), (3 ,1), (2 ,4), (4 ,5), (5 ,6), (6 ,4),
               (6 ,8), (3 ,7), (7 ,8), (8 ,9), (9 ,7), (5 ,10), (10 ,11),
               (11 ,12), (12 ,10), (11 ,13), (13 ,14), (14 ,15), (15 ,13), (15 ,17),
               (12 ,16), (16 ,17), (17 ,18), (18 ,16), (18, 23), (9 ,19), (19 ,20),
               (20 ,21), (21 ,19), (20 ,22), (22 ,23), (23 ,24), (24 ,22), (24 ,26),
               (21 ,25), (25 ,26), (26 ,27), (27 ,25)])

plt.figure()

# set random node labels
node_labels = {node: i for i, node in enumerate(sample(list(H3), H3.number_of_nodes()))}
nx.set_node_attributes(H3, node_labels, 'label')

pos = nx.spring_layout(H3)
nx.draw(
    H3, pos, edge_color='black', width=1, linewidths=1,
    node_size=500, node_color='pink', alpha=0.9,
    labels=node_labels
)

# Calculate harmonious labels for the edges
edge_labels = {(u, v): (node_labels[u] + node_labels[v]) % (H3.number_of_edges()) for u, v in H3.edges}
nx.set_edge_attributes(H3, edge_labels, 'label')

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(
    H3, pos,
    edge_labels=edge_labels,
    font_color='red'
);

Example output:


It's possible like that, but if I want to change sample(list(H3)) to a list from 0 to 38, is it possible? because that is the condition that I use.
